# Getting the boolean value from a cClass

Tags: python, class

I am trying to get the value of a boolean from another Class and the problem is more or less as shown below:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 512
        self.check()

    def check(self):
        if self.value == 512:
            return True

address = Test()
print(address)
```

The output from this is:

```
<__main__.Test object at 0x7f798d17c5b0>
```

I need to get that `True` value from the function inside the class, and is that possible in python. Initially I tried to use the `ctypes` library but it still would not work. Any ideas on how I could solve this problem?

Comment: ```address.check()```. You are printing the instance of the class

Comment: Why are you calling `check()` in the `__init__()` method? And if you need to call it, why don't you use the result?

Comment: Well, actually I am trying to create my own chess game and generally, this problem came in when I wanted my to run my `check_piece()` function simultaneously when the Class Constructor is called out. 

address,check() solves the issue! Looks like I have to find another way to to call out my pieces!

Comment: Im just simulating the same problem to an easier one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the function `check()`. Calling the function in `__init__` will execute the function there.

Also:

> `__init__()` should return `None`, not 'bool'

So, you cannot return anything, except `None`. SO your best bet is to call the function from the instance of the class.

```
address = Test()
print(address.check())
```